# Featured Image of the post are gone after site move to another server

Tags: post-thumbnails

I have moved my wordpress site from Amazon AWS to bluehost with same domain.

1. Setup and Map domain to bluehost.
2. Install wordpress
3. Copy plugin, uploads, and themes folder to new server
4. Dump db and import db

After I load the site, everything is working fine but all featured image of the post are gone even I have already uploaded the "uploads" folder.

When I browse the images from wordpres media library, all image icon is empty image icon.

But I type the image url in browser, i can see the correct image url.

May I know which step I have missed.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: try looking at the site in an incognito window or on another computer, you might just have an old cached copy.

Comment: can you send us the link to your site.

Comment: i think db migration problem and media url not change please db once

Comment: please create old website clone using duplicator plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after I moved one of my sites. The best solution I could come up with was to delete all of the database entries for my media (open the **wp-posts** table, search for all entries with a **post_type** of **attachment** and delete them. Then install the plugin **Add from Server** and I went through each folder, selecting only the parent image (NOT the additional sizes of it that were in the folders) and imported them.

It doesn't duplicate the files that are already on the server, just adds it to the media library. The posts that already had the images used still worked, though they are no longer "attached" to the parent post.

I'm sure there is a better solution, some way to "Rebuild the Media Library" would be awesome. When I had just imported the database from the other site all of the links to the posts were intact and everything looked great, except the images didn't show in the Media Library itself.  If someone figures out a better solution I'd love to hear it, but for me, Add From Server" for the images resolved my need.

Answer (score 0):

My go-to for site moves is WP Clone https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/ . Easiest way to do it, IMHO.

You can do it manually, but I've found it very easy to use WP Clone. It does all of the work involved in moving a site. Works every time I use it.

Your problem is that links to media library are not updated; they are stored with the full URL of the media image. There are database things you can do, but WP Clone is easiest and fastest. (I have no relation to that plugin other than a very satisfied user.)

Answer (score 0):

For site migration and backups I use a plugin as well called Duplicator.  It creates a package that includes the Database and all other files.  It updates URLs automatically, highly recommend this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/